# Where to find the cURL for a network request

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, curl, exoplayer

I need the cURL for a network request for an exoplayer HLS stream.
I am trying to debug a 404 error that is occurring in the handshake with AES encryption on the stream file. I need the cURL to debug the call

Comment: Depends on what networking library exoplayer uses. Something has to generate the command its not just a given, you could try this: https://github.com/mrmike/Ok2Curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used this dependency - https://github.com/grapesnberries/Curl-Logger-interceptor
Add this to your retrofit instance on the call you want to log the CURL